# extract a specific word between two values

Tags: string, bash, split, extract, cut

I curl a html page and stock output into variable, so I try to extract a word between two value, but I failed.

```
 </tr> <tr> <td><a <a href="https://test/one/AAA">AAA</a></td>
 <td>Thu Aug 30 09:59:36 UTC 2018</td> <td align="right"> 2247366 </td>
 <td></td> </tr> <tr> <td><a
 href="https://test/one/1.1.22">1.1.22</a></td> <td>Thu Aug 30 09:59:36
 UTC 2018</td> <td align="right"> 5 </td> <td></td> </tr> </table>
 </body> </html>

 content=$(curl -s https://test/one/)
 echo $content | sed -E 's_.*one/([^"]+).*_\1_'
```

I try to catch value after one/ and before ", so I want to extract AAA,  1.1.22,...

Comment: Use xpath to do so

Comment: Show us what you have tried and failed.

Comment: echo $content | sed 's/.*one/=\(.*\)".*/\1/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ ... | sed -E 's_.*one/([^"]+).*_\1_'

AAA
BBB
```

since you have slash in your content, better to choose a different delimiter, here I used `_`.

*UPDATE*
Since you changed the input file format dramatically, here is the updated script

```
$ echo "$contents" | sed -nE '/one/s_.*one/([^"]+).*_\1_p'
AAA
1.1.22
```

Comment: Never parse HTML with regex

Comment: That's rather dogmatic.  HTML is text and if you don't need the tree structure as in this case, there is nothing wrong with text tools.

Comment: Thanks my friends!! but it gives me just AAA, because AAA, BBB, it is juste an example, more precision, AAA, can be 0.01, 0.2.1, 3.33.1...

Comment: doesn't matter what the content is as long as it doesn't contain `sed` delimiter and quote sign.

Comment: so how I can have the rest ? I have just the first one plz

Comment: what is your test case?  The example you posted works as shown.  Please update the question with more realistic input.

Comment: OK, the reason is you lose newlines since you didn't double quote `$content2`.  The `sed` command as written will only extract one per line.  See the update

Comment: thanks it works, It is imposible for me do to by myself.
thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't parse XML/HTML with regex, use a proper XML/HTML parser and a powerful [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) query.

#### theory :

> According to the compiling theory, XML/HTML can't be parsed using regex based on [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). Due to hierarchical construction of XML/HTML you need to use a [pushdown automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) and manipulate [LALR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser) grammar using tool like [YACC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc).

#### realLife©®™ everyday tool in a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) :

You can use one of the following :

[xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) often installed by default with `libxml2`, xpath1 (check [my wrapper](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/xmllint) to have newlines delimited output

[xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php) can edit, select, transform... Not installed by default, xpath1

[xpath](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath) installed via perl's module XML::XPath, xpath1

[xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) xpath3

[saxon-lint](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint) my own project, wrapper over @Michael Kay's Saxon-HE Java library, xpath3

#### or you can use high level languages and proper libs, I think of :

[python](/questions/tagged/python)'s [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) (`from lxml import etree`)

[perl](/questions/tagged/perl)'s [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod), [`XML::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath), [`XML::Twig::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig), [`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath)

[ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) [nokogiri](/questions/tagged/nokogiri), [check this example](https://sputnick.fr/scripts/parsing-HTML-with-NokogiriXpath.rb.html)

[php](/questions/tagged/php) `DOMXpath`, [check this example](https://sputnick.fr/scripts/parsing-HTML-with-DOMXpath.php.html)

---

Check: [Using regular expressions with HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

---

#### Example using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) :

```
//a[contains(@href, "https://test/sites/two/one")]
```